# Change Device Wallpaper in Python/Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, pyjnius

I have a simple app and,among other things, I need this app to be able to change the wallpaper of a device on Android.

Now, I've looked around on the net and [pyjnius](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) seems like the obvious choice. The problem now is I don't know the first thing about java but a quick google search produces the [WallpaperManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager) as something I could use.

Here's the question: How do I implement that wallpaper manager functionality on my kivy app with pyjnius.
Again, NOT a java dev so don't shoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Java either but after examining some java examples i generated a solution. Don't forget to add **SET_WALLPAPER** permission to your buildozer.spec file. You also need to get storage permission to have this example work.

```
from jnius import autoclass, cast

PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')

try:
    Environment = autoclass("android.os.Environment")
    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
    
    currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
    context = cast('android.content.Context', currentActivity.getApplicationContext())
    
    File = autoclass('java.io.File')
    file = File(path+"/test.jpg")
    
    BitmapFactory = autoclass('android.graphics.BitmapFactory')
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath())
    
    WallpaperManager = autoclass('android.app.WallpaperManager')
    manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context)
    manager.setBitmap(bitmap)
          
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score -1):

Learn java
Systtem.out.println("java");
print("Python")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).